# Unable to find package selenium-webdriver/chrome in npmjs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I require this node module `selenium-webdriver/chrome` to run my script in headless.

I am unable to find this module on https://www.npmjs.com.
From where else I can find this module?

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize(screen))
            .build();
```

Comment: The package's name is `selenium-webdriver`. That's what should be installed, and you'll be able to require `selenium-webdriver/chrome` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

As Evyatar pointed out to you, the module you're looking for is `selenium-webdriver` and not `selenium-webdriver/chrome`, so you're to install `npm install selenium-webdriver --save` then you require `selenium-webdriver`.

Example:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setChromeOptions(/* ... */)
    .setFirefoxOptions(/* ... */)
    .build();
```

This should solve your problem.

You can get to read more on the usage of [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)